# Angular4 (angular-cli) and Material Design Lite (@angular-mdl)

Tags: angular, material-design

I installed material design lite into my angular 4 with this command

```
npm install @angular-mdl/core --save
```

I saw in the instruction that i need to import it

> How to use the mdl components with webpack
>
> Just use it. **Add the MdlModule to your NgModule imports and you are**
>   done!

I tried to import in the app.module.ts

[image]

I don't really see the angular-mdl into my angular 4 project but i see this 
plugin installed succeed
[image]

when i try to use mdl tag i don't see any change in browser, it not effect in my project

Answer (score 0):

try like this:
from '@angular-mdl/core';

Comment: it not show any error, but when i use any tag of mdl it not really effect or do something.

Comment: from the picture it seems that you did not import Mdl module correctly, it should be imported like - import { MdlModule } from '@angular-mdl/core';

Comment: I edited my post, I import as you wrote to me but it doesn't effect on my project when i write any mdl tags